# How to save foreign key value using Hibernate and JPA annotation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes one is user and the other one is ethnicity. Both are having one to one association, ethnicity has a foreign key user_id but the problem is I am getting a null value against the foreign key column in ethnicity table. I am setting these values dynamically using a jsp page.

My mappings are as follow

```
User Class
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Ethnicity ethnicity;
getter/setter


Ethnicity Class
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
public User user;
getter/setter
```

To retrieve the data I am using the same jsp page where I am setting the values. Here is the code how I am retrieving data

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td>${user.userId}</td>
        <td>${user.username}</td>
        <td>${user.password}</td>
        <td>${user.firstName}</td>
        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
        <td>${user.active}</td>
        <td>${user.ethnicity.ethnicityId }</td>
        <td>${user.ethnicity.nationality }</td>
        <td>${user.ethnicity.race }</td>
        <td>${user.ethnicity.region }</td>
        <td>${user.ethnicity.religion }</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Here is one of the function to add the user.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private Mapper mapper; 

@Transactional
public void add(UserDTO userDTO) {
    User user = mapper.map(userDTO, User.class);
    userRepository.save(user);
 }
}
```

User service class extends JpaRepository and for entitymanager I am using maven dependency.

Comment: and how did you persist them? and you set BOTH sides of the relation? and how did you retrieve them?

Comment: where? You post no JPA code, you don't mention how you set the relation up and persisted them

Comment: I am a beginner can you please explain which code you required?

Comment: you tagged this question as JPA and Hibernate. The JPA API puts the data in the database, and retrieves it. Your problem is about what data is in the database. Hence it should be pretty clear that THIS is the code that is needed (EntityManager etc)

Comment: @Bilal, please post code where you have performed ehnicity.setUser(); operation. Any java code that has EntityManager.persist, update, merge.. or whatever operation.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar
Sir I am not performing these operations for ethnicity I am performing these operations only for user I have pasted a code snippet for add operation. All data is getting save in both the entities but the problem is only with the foreign key. I am getting NULL against that column.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar! Reactivating the same question, when I use userDTO.setEthnicity(ethnicity); and ethnicity.setUser(userDTO); I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException. I debug the application and found that ethnicity object is NULL before saving the user. Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- JPA provider does not automatically handle relationship between
  entities based on database values.
- It is the responsibility of application developer to maintain relationship.
- The relationship should be set between **Ethnicity** and **User** i.e. there should be enthnicity set for a user as well as user set for ethnicity as you have created a bidirectional relationship.

  ```
   user.setEthnicity(ethnicity);
   ethnicity.setUser(user);
  ```

This should work.

I've written about [jpa relationshions on www.thejavageek.com](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/17/jpa-one-one-mapping/) where you can find multiple useful tutorials about jpa.

Comment: I am a beginner this is my first experience with this technology I do not know much about all this. Can you please tell me where to add this code?

Comment: @Bilal kindly follow the link provided in the answer. It should solve your problem. If it still doesn't feel free to ask.

Comment: Sir I am doing all this dynamically I'm unable to understand where to put this code. I am not using entitymanager for all this in my java coding. Help needed.

Comment: @Bilal, Oh! I think you are using only hibernate specific code and not JPA.  EntityManager is corresponding to session in hibernate. You need to call save method on user object after doing `user.setEthnicity(ethnicity);` and `ethnicity.setUser(user);` Basically you have to fulfil both relationships from either sides.